# how to get Bitsperpixel from a bitmap

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a 3rd party component which requires me to give it the bitsperpixel from a bitmap.

What's the best way to get "bits per pixel"?

My starting point is the following blank method:-

```
public int GetBitsPerPixelMethod( system.drawing.bitmap bitmap )
{
   //return BitsPerPixel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Pixelformat property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat.aspx), this returns a [Pixelformat enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) which can have values like f.e. `Format24bppRgb`, which obviously is 24 bits per pixel, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
switch(Pixelformat)       
  {
     ...
     case Format8bppIndexed:
        BitsPerPixel = 8;
        break;
     case Format24bppRgb:
        BitsPerPixel = 24;
        break;
     case Format32bppArgb:
     case Format32bppPArgb:
     ...
        BitsPerPixel = 32;
        break;
     default:
        BitsPerPixel = 0;
        break;      
 }
```

Answer (score 107):

Rather than creating your own function, I'd suggest using this existing function in the framework:

```
Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question

Comment: This and only this should be the answer.
Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 8):

```
var source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(pathToImageFile));
int bitsPerPixel = source.Format.BitsPerPixel;
```

The code above requires at least .NET 3.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good answer: testable code-answer, stated assumption (.NET-version) for it to work, and link to documentation. You could probably have used the existing `bitmap` variable/function-argument supplied in the question instead of creating a new one (`source`) in your answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

What about Image.GetPixelFormatSize()?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[Bitmap.PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat(VS.80).aspx)

See [possible values of the PixelFormat property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitmap.PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat.aspx) property will tell you the type of pixel format that the bitmap has, and from that you can infer the number of bits per pixel. I'm not sure if there's a better way of getting this, but the naive way at least would be something like this:

```
var bitsPerPixel = new Dictionary<PixelFormat,int>() {
    { PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, 1 },
    { PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed, 4 },
    { PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, 8 },
    { PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565, 16 }
    /* etc. */
};

return bitsPerPixel[bitmap.PixelFormat];
```