# Get raw pixel value in bitmap image

Tags: c#

How can I get bits per pixel in bitmap image? example if pixel `x=24` & `y=45` has RGB `123`,`212`,`112` so it must return `1111011`, `11010100`, `1110000`.

Comment: That's not bits per pixel; bits per pixel is a function of the number of colors the image data can encode (or the other way around, if you prefer). Improved title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not specific to pixels, basically need to get bits for the bytes:

You can use a static extension:

```
    public static string ToBitString(this byte b)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8);
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sb.Append((b & (1 << i)) > 0 ? '1' : '0');
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

And use:

```
        byte bt = 120;
        Console.WriteLine(bt.ToBitString());
                    // outputs 01111000
```

In your case:

```
   Color c = ...;
   string s = ((byte) c.B).ToBitString();
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the bits per pixel use this function:

```
Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat)
```

For more information you can read [this](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/graphics/143830/143830/how-many-bytes-in-a-bitmap-pixel/?S=B20000) answer as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126967/how-to-get-bitsperpixel-from-a-bitmap).

Answer (score 1):

Load the file into a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), get the [Pixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx), and read the [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) information from it, which will get you a Byte for each of R, G and B.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap ("C:\image.bmp");
Color color = bmp.GetPixel(24, 45);
Debug.WriteLine (string.Format ("R={0}, G={1}, B={2}", color.R, color.G, color.B));
```

See Aliostad's answer for how to convert this into a binary string. I think the question isn't entirely clear on what you require.

Comment: `GetPixel` is *very* slow, so don't use this if you need to loop over all pixels in the bitmap.